# How to maintain git branch as independent to each other?

Tags: git

I would like to maintain master branch and b1 branch as independent to each other, this is how I've done so far.

I created a brandnew branch called b1

```
git branch b1
git checkout b1
```

I open sublime and edited a file called f1.txt, and saved it.

I switch to the master branch

```
git checkout master
```

I displayed the content of the file

```
cat f1.txt
```

Why I can see the "additional line" I just added when I was on the b1 branch

What did I do wrong???

Please help, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository)

Comment: Did you commit your changes or only saved a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of git.

You can use **-f** flag to checkout to do "clean checkout" if you like.

The key to remember is that the file was not modified in the `b1` branch. It was only modified in your working copy.

Only when you commit are the changes put back into whichever branch you have checked out

It's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246275/modified-files-in-a-git-branch-are-spilling-over-into-another-branch)

Answer (score 1):

You always had to commit the changes before switching to another branch. For example:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "test"
```

and now you can switch to the new branch. For example:

```
git branch test
```

You can also read my blog post on this topic: http://www.deanpodgornik.si/how-to-collaborate-using-git-merging-simplified/