# Git changes reflecting in parent branch automatically from other remote branch

Tags: git

I have created a remote branch B from another branch A.

```
git branch B
git checkout B
```

and did some changes in B and checked git status.

Now when I checkout A and same changes are reflecting in A git status.

```
git checkout A
git status
```

might sound very silly but Why?...I am new to git

Comment: You haven't staged (git add) or committed (git commit) anything to your B branch.

Comment: I did "git add -A"  in branch B...but still same status for both branch

Comment: but you didn't do `git commit` after `git add`, did you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modified files in a git branch are spilling over into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246275/modified-files-in-a-git-branch-are-spilling-over-into-another-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246298/7976758