# Changes from one branch are also applied (kept) in other branches? (PhpStorm & Git)

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2018.2.4 (Ubuntu 18).

Let's say that I've pulled the `develop` branch from GitHub repo (project) and there are 2 files in the project:

- file_1.php
- file_2.php

Then I create a new branch in PhpStorm named `feature/something` and checkout ( *in the Branches popup, I choose **New Branch**, select **Checkout branch** option and enter name* ... ).

Now I'm on `feature/something`.

I do some changes in *file_1.php* and in the PhpStorm's file browser it becomes **blue** (as expected).

BUT, when I go (checkout) back to `develop` branch - the changes I've made when I was on `feature/something` are kept (are also applied) on `develop` branch:

- *file_1.php* is still 'blue'
- changes in *file_1.php* are there...

Is this supposed to work like that OR when I move back (checkout) to `develop` branch - the changes from `feature/something` should not be applied (kept) in `develop`?

- If this is normal - then how can I move back to the "original" (clean) `develop` (without the chages from the other local branch)? If I do `revert` while on `develop` - then when I move (checkout) back to the `feature/something` - those changes were reverted there too.
- If this is not supposed to work like this, how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modified files in a git branch are spilling over into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246275/modified-files-in-a-git-branch-are-spilling-over-into-another-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't commit those changes, the changes are kept irrespective of the checked out branch. If checking out another branch would conflict with those changes, Git would tell you that. So, stage and commit the changes on your feature branch if you want to keep them. If you then check out develop, it won't show those changes.

See also [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053757/checkout-another-branch-when-there-are-uncommitted-changes-on-the-current-branch).