# Git checkout is moving file from feature branch to dev branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have read the official git checkout documentation and some questions here and haven't found an answer to the behaviour I'm seeing.

Locally, I have a dev branch. From within the dev branch, I create a new feature branch

```
git checkout -b myBranch
```

Then, I add a new file

```
echo foo > myFile.txt
```

If I immediately go back to the dev branch

```
git checkout dev
```

the myFile.txt is already there, even though

1) I did not stage the file
2) I haven't merged the branches

My expectation is that any changes I make to the files while in the feature branch will not propagate over the other branches.

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you don't `commit` or `stash` the changes then the changes will go the branch you checking out

Comment: I confirmed this to be the expected behaviour, thanks @SajibKhan

Comment: To add to the previous two comments, `myFile.txt` is not in branch `dev` yet either, it's just in your sandbox, untracked. Even a `git reset --hard` won't touch untracked files. The only command I know that touches untracked files is `git stash --include-untracked`.

Comment: @phd that's not really the right duplicate, but I can't find a good one.

Comment: @torek https://stackoverflow.com/a/246285/7976758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[E.Omar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54673850/1256452) is correct (and upvoted), but it's worth emphasizing that your *work-tree*—the place where you see, and work with, your files—*is not a branch*.  It is not a commit, and it will not be preserved!  It is merely the place where you *do your work*.

What *will* be preserved—forever, or as long as the commit itself exists, anyway—is the *complete snapshot* that you make when you make a *new* commit.  But this snapshot is not a copy of your *work-tree* at all!  Instead, it is a snapshot of what you put into Git's *index*.

The index—which is also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*—is a complicated thing, but it is, I think, best thought of as: *All the files that Git will put into the **next** commit that you make, when you make it.*  It starts out being a copy of all of the files saved in the commit that you checked out when you ran `git checkout name`.

If you create a new file in your work-tree, or after you have modified an existing file, *nothing has happened to the index*.  It's still a copy of what was in the *commit*.  Running `git add` tells Git to copy the file from the work-tree into the index, making it ready to go into the *next* commit.  Until then, it's just a file in the work-tree: an *untracked* file, if there's no copy of it in the index.

See also [the answer that phd linked-to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246285/1256452) in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671660/git-checkout-is-moving-file-from-feature-branch-to-dev-branch#comment96140969_54671660) on the question [Modified files in a git branch are spilling over into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246275/1256452) (which we've used as a duplicate for a closer for this question).  Note that causing the new file to become tracked (by `git add`-ing the new file) is not sufficent: you must also run `git commit` to make a new commit that contains a frozen-forever copy of the file (plus, of course, all the other files).  Until then, it's just an untracked or tracked file, but not in any commit.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you created the new file while you are on the new branch but you haven't **tracked** it. Therefor the new file isn't only exist on the new branch, instead it belongs to the working directory and not to any specific branch.