# Git applies changes to master branch when on other branch

Tags: git

I have a file on master branch, I have then created a new branch `new` and wrote a few print statements. I then checkout onto master, and the same changes are on master aswell. I have not pushed the changes from `new`.

How is that possible?

Comment: Are there any actual committed changes to that file between master and new? If switching between branches doesn't introduce changes to files you have modified, it will leave the file untouched and will still contain your modifications.

Comment: Why would it contain modifications on another branch than the one I'm working on ?

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246298/7976758

Answer (score 0):

Because most likely you have not committed your changes to the `new` branch.

Rather they are just dangling around in an uncommitted, possibly unstaged state.

Type `git status` to confirm this theory.  Also, at any given point switch back to the `new` branch via `git checkout new` and then type `git log` or `git log -p` (-p is to view changes in the commit) to see if you have committed your work on the `new` branch.