# IntelliJ-Git: Why my classes from one branch show in a checkout of another branch?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, git-branch, vcs-checkout

1. I checked out `master` and then created a branch out of it (with checkout): `patchA`
2. I made some changes, committed, pushed, even made a pull request for branch `patchA`
3. Pull Request has not yet been reviewed (and not yet merged into `master`, of course)
4. I then created another branch out of `master` (with checkout): `patchB`
5. I made some changes, didn't even commit those...

*** Now, I wanted to take a look into `patchA`, so I checked it out - I see my changes that I pushed but also the changes I made in `patchB` !

Why is that? I thought the whole idea of branches is to isolate work, to make things a little neater for delivering units of work and reviewing them...

More info: When checking out `patchB`, I don't see the changes from `patchA`

Comment: Uncommited changes aren't reverted when switching branches. If they were, you'd lose them very easily. In other words: these changes don't "belong" to `patchB` in any meaningful way: only once they are commited will the be associated with that branch.

Comment: that makes sense. I committed and the patchA stuff disappeared from patchB. Thank you! BTW: I can see why this is useful but it's a little weird to see changes unrelated to the branch show up :)

Comment: "*I made some changes, **didn't even commit** those*" That's the culprit. https://stackoverflow.com/a/246298/7976758: "*The key to remember is that the file was **not** modified in the … branch. It was only modified in your working copy.*" — *Gareth*