# Edit and create more text files in git with command line

Tags: windows, git, text, cmd

I'm trying to learn using git in windows with command line. I want create a txt file in master, then create 2 branches and modify text differently but I have a problem.

I succesfully create repository file. Then I add the file and commit it. No problem until this point.

After this I create and checkout to new branch with code:

```
git checkout -b feature2
```

Then I open the text with notepad(with command) and modify and save it.

Then checkout to master and when I open the text it is modified version. So I can not create third branch with different text.

It seems that there is only one text file to all branches. What do I miss?

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246298/7976758

Comment: You should add and commit your changes before switching branches.