# File added to branch dev is showing in another branch when checking out and without merging visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I have two branches `dev` and `bugfix`

on dev I have created new file `TestClass.cs` this file is not staged.
If I run `git status` it shows

```
On branch dev
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        WebApplication1/TestClass.cs

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Then I run `git checkout bugfix`
Now I can see the newly added class `TestClass.cs` in this branch as well.

so if I run `git status` it shows

```
On branch bugfix
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        WebApplication1/TestClass.cs

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Can someone explain to me this behavior? why this file is being shared between them?
I came to know that I should have staged then stash this file before checking out.

But still I want to understand this behavior. Why it's not kept for dev branch only?
sometimes I forget to stage and stash changes before checking out and it creates a huge mess

Comment: The same symptom with modified files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246298/7976758. In your case it's an untracked file that doesn't belong to Git at all. Not to any branch.

Comment: Unstaged files means untracked files. i,e git does not know which branch that file belongs to. So unless you explicitly stage it in a particular branch, git will show that file in all branches. It really is  irrelevant in which branch you create that file until you explicitly stage that file in a particular branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until it is committed into git, (i.e. while the file is untracked), it is not on *any* branch. So no matter which branch you are on, the file will still be there locally.

Comment: This a surprisingly simple but accurate answer. It made me realise that the file that persisted was a new file, not committed to any branch. Thanks.