# SourceTree seems not distinguish what branch I'm working on

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Starting from the branch develop I created a separated branch feature and I made my changes on that. When I open SourceTree, it correctly notifies me I have some commits to do on feature branch but if I checkout to develop it notifies the same commits and the two local branches appear to be the same even if I worked exclusively on feature. This is creating me lots of problems since I'm working with a team. Is there a reson for this? what could I do?

Comment: Reading this it sounds like you did changes to files but did not commit them onto the branch. Also note, this question might get flagged off-topic because it is not about programing, rather than using a tool => superuser.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246298/7976758

Comment: @DanielW. It's still programming related? That's why there's a tag for it

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's debatable. "How to use SourceTree" does not involve any programming. It's not worth arguing about, that's why I didn't cast a close-vote either.

Comment: @DanielW. no arguing needed. 