# How to use Open OnDemand and git at the same time

Tags: git

On the university cluster that I use, they use Open OnDemand for GUI file management system.  I do some minor coding using the Editor that it has.  I use `git` to manage my project.  A strange thing is happening: when I do

```
git branch new_feature
git checkout new_feature
```

then open `main.py` using Open OnDemand, make a small change, save it, then

```
git checkout master
cat main.py
```

the change has been made on the `master` branch as well.  It seems to me this has something to do with how Open OnDemand works.  How can I use git, but also use Open OnDemand?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246298/7976758

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modified files in a git branch are spilling over into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246275/modified-files-in-a-git-branch-are-spilling-over-into-another-branch)

Comment: Looks Like I made the (common?) mistake of thinking of the branches as literal copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what OnDemand would be doing *but* in strict git terms, as long as you do *not* commit a change, git will move that change along when you do a checkout with uncommitted changes (some conditions are checked which might get git to reject the checkout). Given that you are not explainig that you committed, I think that is the root cause.

Comment: How do I keep the two branches separate enough that I can run a program in `master`, which requires me to make small changes to a config file, all the while developing `new_feature` without `master` trying to use files I've modified in `new_feature`?

Comment: You need to _commit_ the changes to one branch, that is the whole point of branches, being able to have code/files that move in different directions.

Comment: I'm new to git, but advice I saw recommended that I commit when I have a version I might want to come back to.  But, from what you're saying, it looks like I'll need to buck the advice to be able to accomplish what I want to do.  For example, I might need to commit an unfinished line of code so that I can return to master and run that code I want there.

Comment: You can also take advantage of the stash when you want to save something that is not ready for a commit. `git help stash`

Comment: Still, there's the difficulty of the fact that I submit SLURM jobs to a queue in the cluster, and they may not run right away.  I don't know when they'll run, and if I'm in `new_feature`, rather than `master`, they'll run on the wrong code.

Comment: Perhaps using separate worktrees? You can have more than one worktree per repo.