# How can I switch between master and a new feature branch using Git?

Tags: git

I'm new using git branches. What I want to do is a new feature keeping the original master in case I need to go back and do something else from there.

For this purpose I did the following:

```
git branch new feature
git checkout newfeature
```

From `newfeature` branch, I made a fair amount of changes (I modified 78 files). Here is a summary of the git status:

```
On branch newfeature
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   //a long list of 60 files

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        // a long list of 18 files

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What I didn't expect is that when I go back to `master` with the `git checkout master` command, I see all the changes as if I were in the newfeature branch. Here is a summary of the git status of the master:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
            modified:   //a long list of 60 files

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
            // a long list of 18 files

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How can I switch between the original master (which should not have the changes) and the newfeature (which contains the changes to all 78 files)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246298/7976758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I switch between the original master (which should not have the changes) and the newfeature (which contains the changes to all 78 files)?

Git is about *commits*. A branch is a *commit*. You need to make a *commit*.

While on the `newfeature` branch say

```
git add .
git commit -m 'your message here'
```

Now `newfeature` is a *commit* containing the changed versions of those files. So changing to the `master` *commit*...

```
git switch master
```

...and back to the `newfeature` *commit*...

```
git switch newfeature
```

...will alternate as you were hoping.

Comment: And read https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/