git switch -c keeping changes in both branches
I have made some changes in my master branch. I want to switch those changes to a new branch and restore master branch back to where it was before changes.
I used git switch -c <new-branch> command.
It created a new branch with all the changes I had done in master which is good, but when switching back to master the changes are still present in the master branch.
I thought the behavior would be that it would reset master and move the changes to the new-branch.
I am afraid to discard changes in master as it may discard them in the new-branch?
Is there a different command that will allow me to achieve moving all changes to a new branch and discarding those changes in main?
I also tried git checkout -b <new-branch>
Thank you.

If you have not committed those changes, then it is expected behavior. Once you commit them, they will stop following you around and they will remain in the branch/commit where you committed them.

Thanks for the sanity check. Am I correct that if I discard the changes in master then they will be discarded in the new-branch as well?

If you have not committed the changes in any branch, then that is correct. In my case, if I forget to check out to a new branch before making all my changes, I perform git checkout -b  to checkout to a new branch, then commit my changes in that branch. Otherwise, if you already committed your changes in a new branch, then you should not be able to see those changes when you switch back to master.

Alternatively, you could also git stash your changes, make a new branch, then git stash apply your changes but that's kinda overkill for this scenario, although it can be useful in certain other scenarios.

It sounds like you haven't committed the changes yet. Uncommitted changes do not exist on any branch yet. If you have not committed yet, then do not undo those changes! Commit them first. (BTW, it's better to commit on the wrong branch than not at all. Once committed you can move commits around later, but until then, you could potentially still lose your work.)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246275/modified-files-in-a-git-branch-are-spilling-over-into-another-branch

I always feel that commits are kinda permanent and then I get wary on how to exactly unwind them, even more so if I have added more changes after the commit. However, your comment leads me to believe I should not be as afraid of committing code and reverting it as I have been.

Perhaps this will help get you in the right mood to work with git: Commits are permanent.... but branches are not. You can't modify a commit once it is created (say, if you amend a commit, you are not really modifying that commit... it's a new commit) but branches are just pointers to commits that you move around at will... you might commit on a wrong branch (locally, of course), then you could checkout the right branch, cherry-pick what you committed in the wrong branch before and then move the pointer of the wrong branch to the previous commit so that it loses the wrong commit.
